# counting records connected to specific table mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MYSQL database called following news and views. News contain information about the news where views basically contain information about the view and a newsId. What i want is to retrieve all the news with the number of views connected to it. here is what i've tried so far, however it seem to only return 1 row.

```
SELECT 
n.id, 
n.title, 
n.image_url, 
n.date,
Count(v.news_id)
from news n
join views v on v.news_id = n.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aggregate function` without `group by` returns always one row, so you need to add a `group by` clause

```
SELECT 
n.id, 
n.title, 
n.image_url, 
n.date,
Count(v.news_id)
from news n
join views v on v.news_id = n.id
group by n.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about Group by

```
SELECT n.id, n.title, n.image_url, n.date,Count(v.news_id)
from news n
join views v on v.news_id = n.id
Group by n.id
```